# How to support Slide In Out animation in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation, swiftui

**Context**

Hey there, I am working on a `SwiftUI` App and am currently implementing `InApp Notifications`.

I would like to mimic the behaviour of the standard iOS Notifications: *Slide in from to top and slide out to the top.*

---

**Code**

```swift
struct NotificationView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var notificationVM = NotificationViewModel.shared

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                Group {
                    if let safeNotification = notificationVM.activeNotification {
                        Notification(with: safeNotification)
                    }
                }
                .animation(.spring())
                .position(x: geometry.size.width / 2, y: notificationVM.activeNotification == nil ? -500 : geometry.safeAreaInsets.top)
            }
                
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Questions**

- This implementation does only work sometimes: The sliding in works most of the time (just the first appearance is not animated), while the sliding out never works.
- the `.animation` Modifier throws a warning: `'animation' was deprecated in iOS 15.0: Use withAnimation or animation(_:value:) instead.` How to use this Modifier with `value`?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/65856845/12299030?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct NotificationView: View {

    @State private var showNotification = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            SuccessNotification()
                .offset(y: showNotification ? (-UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 3) : -UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
                .animation(.interpolatingSpring(mass: 1.0, stiffness: 100.0, damping: 10, initialVelocity: 0), value: showNotification)
            Button("Press me") { showNotification.toggle() }
        }
    }
}

struct NotificationView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NotificationView()
    }
}

struct SuccessNotification: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Success")
            .padding()
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 10, height: 100)
            .background(.green, in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
    }
}
```

'animation' was deprecated in iOS 15.0
So just use the @State that changes the animation as the value :

```
@State private var showNotification = false

.animation(.linear, value: showNotification)
```