# SwiftUI: how to make a view disappear with a slide to the top?

Tags: animation, swiftui, transition

I would like to make a view disappear with a transition to the top, but I have no idea how to do this with SwiftUI. Here is my code so far:

```
struct MyList: View {
    @State private var loading = true
    @State private var elements: [MyElement] = []

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.white
            List(elements) {
                ListRow($0)
            }
            if loading {
                LoadingView() // This is the view I want to slide to the top when hiding
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            callAPI() { elements in
                self.elements = elements
                self.loading = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to hide the LoadingView() with a slide-to-top transition, but don't know how.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/65856845/12299030?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `.transition` modifier.

[documentation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi2x93q_eT3AhV2gP0HHSIOBGMQFnoECAYQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Ftutorials%2Fswiftui%2Fanimating-views-and-transitions&usg=AOvVaw3QNkfvApTQH0x4eF__ynG6)

```
LoadingView()
     .transition(.move(edge: .top))
```

But don´t forget to animate it:

```
.onAppear {
        self.loading = true
        callAPI() { elements in
            self.elements = elements

            DispatchQueue.main.async { // as this is probably from background Thread dispatch it
               self.loading = false
             }
        }
    }.animation(.default, value: loading)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code will be looks like:

```
struct MyList: View {
    @State private var loading = true
    @State private var elements: [MyElement] = []

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.white
            List(elements) {
                ListRow($0)
            }
            if loading {
                LoadingView()
                    .transition(.move(edge: .top))
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                    .zIndex(1)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            callAPI() { elements in
                self.elements = elements
                withAnimation {
                   self.loading = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You also add .zIndex(1) for avoiding missing animation while disappearing